# FlatList : detect when top reached after scrolling

Tags: react-native

Is there an easy way to know when the user scrolls back up to top in a FlatList?

Specifically

1. FlatList renders normally
2. User scrolls down
3. And then user scrolls back to the top

I am looking to get an easy way to detect event #3.

I have looked at using onScroll and using the nativeEvent y offsets but is there an easier or more elegant solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way I found involves the e.nativeEvent.contentOffset.y
I noticed that the e.nativeEvent.contentOffset.y becomes 0 on Android when on top
while can become negative on iOS (over scroll)

To be able to act when user just starts to scroll from the top and when the user scrolls back right to the top, the following works fine for me.

(sample using a component)

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props)
  this.yOffset = 0;
}


onScroll = (e) => {
  if (this.yOffset <= 0 && e.nativeEvent.contentOffset.y > 0) {
    // case when user just started scrolling down from the top
  } else if (this.yOffset > 0 && e.nativeEvent.contentOffset.y <= 0){
    // case when the user scrolls back to the top
  }
  this.yOffset = e.nativeEvent.contentOffset.y;
}
```